# How to edit shortcut language in Powerpoint?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, language

I have been working at a company for several years, and that company is using a English installation of Microsoft Powerpoint. In this installation, I've learned the hotkeys, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>→<kbd>N</kbd>→<kbd>X</kbd> to insert a text box.

Now I've changed company, and they use Swedish installs. I now need to press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>→<kbd>N</kbd>→<kbd>X</kbd>→<kbd>3</kbd> by some reason. Other shortcuts have gotten significantly worse than this example, but the main problem for me is that I need to relearn a LOT of hotkeys.

Can I change the hotkey language of the installation? Or possibly change the language in Powerpoint altogether?

---

For future reference. I have *Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019, version 1808*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may install a
[Language Accessory Pack for Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f#ID0EAADAAA=Newer_versions).

This is described as:

> Language packs add additional display, help, and proofing tools to Office

so I don't know whether it includes hotkeys.

In any case, once Office has been activated, you can always "upgrade" it to
another Office of the same version, but in another language.
Office should stay activated, but just in case you should make sure you have the
serial key before starting.

The easiest method is as described in the Microsoft article
[Download and install or reinstall Office 2016 or Office 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2016-or-office-2013-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479),
which requires a Microsoft account associated with your copy of Office.

This is also different for Office 365 or Office 2016/2019 (or other),
so if the above is not enough, let us know your Office version.

Comment: It does indeed work! Editing "Display and Help languages", as described in the link fixed it. I have a managed installation, and cannot install extra language packs, but English language pack was already installed! Thank you!